# Transactional Design Pattern

Tags: sharepoint, design-patterns, transactions

I have a need to create a "transactional" process using an external API that does not support COM+ or .NET transactions (Sharepoint to be exact)

What I need to do is to be able to perform a number of processes in a sequence, but any failure in that sequence means that I will have to manually undo all of the previous steps.  In my case there are only 2 types of step, both af which are fairly easy to undo/roll back.

Does anyony have any suggestions for design patterns or structures that could be usefull for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your changes are done to the SharePoint object model, you can use the fact that changes are not committed until you call the `Update()` method of the modified object, such as `SPList.Update()` or `SPWeb.Update()`.

Otherwise, I would use the *Command* Design Pattern. Chapter 6 in [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) even has an example that implements the undo functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The GoF Command Pattern supports undoable operations.

I think the same pattern can be used for sequential operations (sequential commands).

Answer (score 2):

Another good way for rollback/undo is the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). It's usually used to take a snapshot of the object at a given time and let the object state to be reverted to the memento.

Answer (score 1):

Next to the GOF [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Pattern) you might also want to have a look at the [Transaction Script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) pattern from [P of EAA](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa).

You should probably create a Composite Command (or Transaction Script) that executes in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Compensating Resource Manager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xkdw05k(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ (or any other language with deterministic destructor execution when scopes end) you can take a look at [Scope Guards](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758). This technique can probably also be adapted to .NET by making ScopeGuard implement IDisposable and sprinkling "using" statements as needed.